# Vue: Reacting to input change on array of inputs in v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have an array of values I am setting the initial data value `list` to.  I am using that list to render the values of the array in inputs.  I am rendering the value of the input in a `v-for` using: `<input :value="element" />`.  I tried using `v-model` but I get the error:

```
<input v-model="element">: You are binding v-model directly to a v-for iteration alias. This will not be able to modify the v-for source array because writing to the alias is like modifying a function local variable. Consider using an array of objects and use v-model on an object property instead.
```

```
    data() {
        let sizeFilterArray = this.$store.getters['main/getSizeFilters'];
        return {
            list: sizeFilterArray,
        }
    },
```

---

```
<draggable v-model="list">
   <div v-for="(element,index) in list" :key="index">
        <div class="element-box">
            <div class="element-input">
                <input :value="element" />
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</draggable>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is directing you to use an array of objects instead of values. So, you could modify to:

```
<draggable v-model="list">
   <div v-for="item in list" :key="item.id">
        <div class="element-box">
            <div class="element-input">
                <input v-model="item.value" />
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</draggable>
```

This assumes your `sizeFilterArray` is an array of objects like `{ id: 1, value: someValue }`.

Comment: thanks!  I manipulated my array on the backend to be an array of objects and that worked!  thanks!